# How to delete a hidden input added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a list of products added from a `select` in a form using jQuery.
After the addition of those products, I would like to send them with the rest of the `form`.

The question is when I delete a product, I would also like to remove the hidden input created before.

Could you someone please give me a hand.

Thanks!!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form-receta" id="form-receta">
  <label for="nombre_receta">Nombre :</label><input id="nombre_receta" name="name_receta" type="text">

  <label for="nombre_ingr">Ingredientes:</label><br />
  <select style="width:7.7em;display: inline-block;" id="nombre_ingr" name="nombre_ingr">
<option></option>
<option value="1*Prueba">Prueba</option>
<option value="2*Test">Test</option>
  </select>
  <input  id="cantidad_ingr" name="cantidad_ingr" placeholder="cantidad" type="text">
  <input  id="um_ingr" name="um_ingr" placeholder="U.M" type="text">
  <button type="button" class="add-row">ADD</button>
  <h3>Ingredientes</h3>
  <table>
<tr >
  <th>#</th>  
  <th></th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>U.M</th>
  <th>Eliminar</th>            
</tr>
<tbody id="tabla-ingr"></tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 0;
  $(".add-row").click(function(){
    var id_nombre = $("#nombre_ingr").val();
    var res = id_nombre.split("*");


    var nombre = res[1];
    var id = res[0];
    var cantidad = $("#cantidad_ingr").val();
    var um = $("#um_ingr").val();
    x = x + 1;
    var markup = "<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + nombre + "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + cantidad + 
        "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + um + "</td><td class=\"text-center\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger removebutton\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>DEL</button></tr>";
    $("tbody#tabla-ingr").append(markup);


    $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_id_ingr[]" value="'+ id +'" />');
    $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_cantidad_ingr[]" value="'+ cantidad +'" />');
    $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_um_ingr[]" value="'+ um +'" />');
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
  });

});
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an **id** to those input hidden elements. Then, when you delete the row, you can look for the id of that specific row and delete only the input hidden related to that row.

I hope it makes sense!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = 0;
  $(".add-row").click(function(){
      var id_nombre = $("#nombre_ingr").val();
      var res = id_nombre.split("*");


      var nombre = res[1];
      var id = res[0];
      var cantidad = $("#cantidad_ingr").val();
      var um = $("#um_ingr").val();
      x = x + 1;
      var markup = "<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + nombre + "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + cantidad + 
      "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + um + "</td><td class=\"text-center\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger removebutton\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>DEL</button></tr>";
      $("tbody#tabla-ingr").append(markup);


      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_id_ingr[]" id="_id_ingr_'+x+'" value="'+ id +'" />');
      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_cantidad_ingr[]" id="_cantidad_ingr_'+x+'" value="'+ cantidad +'" />');
      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_um_ingr[]" id="_um_ingr_'+x+'" value="'+ um +'" />');
  });

   $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
       var ingrediente_row = $(this).closest('tr');
       var ingrediente_id = $(ingrediente_row).children('td')[0].innerHTML;
       
       $('#_id_ingr_' + ingrediente_id).remove();
       $('#_cantidad_ingr_' + ingrediente_id).remove();
       $('#_um_ingr_' + ingrediente_id).remove();
       $(ingrediente_row).remove();
       
       return false;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form-receta" id="form-receta">
  <label for="nombre_receta">Nombre :</label><input id="nombre_receta" name="name_receta" type="text">
    
  <label for="nombre_ingr">Ingredientes:</label><br />
 <select style="width:7.7em;display: inline-block;" id="nombre_ingr" name="nombre_ingr">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1*Prueba">Prueba</option>
    <option value="2*Test">Test</option>
 </select>
  <input  id="cantidad_ingr" name="cantidad_ingr" placeholder="cantidad" type="text">
  <input  id="um_ingr" name="um_ingr" placeholder="U.M" type="text">
 <button type="button" class="add-row">ADD</button>
</form>

<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<table>
  <tr >
   <th>#</th> 
   <th></th>
   <th>Cantidad</th>
   <th>U.M</th>
   <th>Eliminar</th>      
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tabla-ingr"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a specific class for each hidden field and and pass this no to delete button :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x=0;
  $(".add-row").click(function(){
      var id_nombre = $("#nombre_ingr").val();
      var res = id_nombre.split("*");


      var nombre = res[1];
      var id = res[0];
      var cantidad = $("#cantidad_ingr").val();
      var um = $("#um_ingr").val();
      x = x + 1;
      var markup = "<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + nombre + "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + cantidad + 
      "</td><td class=\"text-center\">" + um + "</td><td class=\"text-center\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger removebutton\" data-id='"+x+"'><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span>DEL</button></tr>";
      $("tbody#tabla-ingr").append(markup);


      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_id_ingr[]" class="_hidden_'+x+'" value="'+ id +'" />');
      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_cantidad_ingr[]" class="_hidden_'+x+'" value="'+ cantidad +'" />');
      $('#form-receta').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="_um_ingr[]" class="_hidden_'+x+'" value="'+ um +'" />');
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
    $('._hidden_'+$(this).data('id')).remove();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form-receta" id="form-receta">
  <label for="nombre_receta">Nombre :</label><input id="nombre_receta" name="name_receta" type="text">

  <label for="nombre_ingr">Ingredientes:</label><br />
  <select style="width:7.7em;display: inline-block;" id="nombre_ingr" name="nombre_ingr">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1*Prueba">Prueba</option>
    <option value="2*Test">Test</option>
 </select>
  <input id="cantidad_ingr" name="cantidad_ingr" placeholder="cantidad" type="text">
  <input id="um_ingr" name="um_ingr" placeholder="U.M" type="text">
  <button type="button" class="add-row">ADD</button>
</form>

<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>U.M</th>
    <th>Eliminar</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tabla-ingr"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use Jquery selected `type=hidden` to remove too, while you click remove botton.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $('[type=hidden]').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: hew... This will remove ALL hidden inputs.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette there's have another hidden input you want to keep? I saw whole page the hidden input only every time while I click add button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input[type="hidden"]` to remove `input` elements alone.

**Code snippets:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $('#form-receta input[type="hidden"]').remove();
    return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wc1mr8mw/)

Answer (score 0):

If the hidden inputs were added using `append()`, the order of these inputs woud be the same as shown in the `table`.

So there is 3 hidden fields created on each `ADD` click.
On `DEL` click, we know on wich row the click occured.
So we can deduct the `index` of the 3 hidden fields to remove.

In your HTML, I added `<div id="hiddenInputList"></div>` in the `form`.

Then in the code, to append the hidden fields:

```
  // Append the hidden fields to a div, in the same order as the table.
  $('#hiddenInputList').append('<input type="hidden" name="_id_ingr[]" value="'+ id +'" />');
  $('#hiddenInputList').append('<input type="hidden" name="_cantidad_ingr[]" value="'+ cantidad +'" />');
  $('#hiddenInputList').append('<input type="hidden" name="_um_ingr[]" value="'+ um +'" />');
```

And then, to remove them:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {

  var thisTR = $(this).closest("tr");
  var thisTR_Index = thisTR.index();
  console.log("thisTR_Index: "+thisTR_Index);

  // Delete the 3 hidden fields (Must do it in the revers order)
  $('#hiddenInputList').find("[type='hidden']").eq((thisTR_Index*3)+2).remove();
  $('#hiddenInputList').find("[type='hidden']").eq((thisTR_Index*3)+1).remove();
  $('#hiddenInputList').find("[type='hidden']").eq(thisTR_Index*3).remove();

  // Remove the table row.
  thisTR.remove();
  return false;
});
```

In this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KqQaPK), to be make it a visual example... Instead of hidden fields, I used classes.
Added fields are green. And on `DEL` click, we can see that re right ones are targeted because they turn red.